# deploy a MySQL database on the remote server

Tags: mysql, database, deployment, synchronization, copy

I have a local MySQL databases and I want to deploy it on the remote server.

There is some tool in PhpMyAdmin to synchronize local and remote databases, however is very slow if you have large databases, as in my case.

Is there a better and a faster way ? Such as shell through ssh, or something else ?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888604/syncing-remote-database-to-local

Comment: this is how to get the remote db to your localhost PC, but I need to put my local db to the remote server.

Comment: You should rephrase your question. You are not trying to synchronize your DBs, you are trying to copy and deploy a snapshot. For synchronization, look to mysql replication.

Comment: True, I am trying to copy it. I have rephrased my question, thanks correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fond a solution:

```
mysqldump -u my_local_db_username --password=my_local_db_password --host=localhost -C my_local_db_name | ssh user@www.my_domain.com "mysql -u my_remote_db_username --password=my_remote_db_password my_remote_db_name"
```

source: [here](http://blog.4webby.com/posts/view/9/mysql_how_to_syncronize_remote_and_local_databases_with_shell_and_ssh)